# Error Creating TActivityIndicator at Runtime

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10-seattle

I saw the introduction of the TActivityIndicator in Delphi 10 Seattle and thought cool I could make use of this somewhere. I wanted to use this to show that some dynamically created sections of my form were still loading the data before populating the form. So I thought I'd do this before I start loading my data in `FormShow`, where self is the form.

```
indicator := TActivityIndicator.Create(self);
indicator.IndicatorSize := TActivityIndicatorSize.aisLarge;
```

Sadly when I try to create them dynamically and set then `TActivityIndicator.IndicatorSize` I get an exception `... EInvalidOperation with message 'Control '<name>' has no parent window'` Which stepping through the VCL takes me to `Vcl.Controls TWinControl.CreateWnd` specifically

```
if (WndParent = 0) and (Style and WS_CHILD <> 0) then
  if (Owner <> nil) and (csReading in Owner.ComponentState) and
    (Owner is TWinControl) then
    WndParent := TWinControl(Owner).Handle
  else
    raise EInvalidOperation.CreateFmt(SParentRequired, [Name]);
```

I've checked `Owner` is the form which is of course a TWinControl but `(csReading in Owner.ComponentState)` returns false. Stepping through Owner.ComponentState = [] on FormCreate and [csFreeNotification] on FormShow.

I've found that if you try to change the `IndicatorSize` of a TActivityIndicator that was created at design time then it works perfectly. So what am I missing here or is it not possible to create `TActivityIndicators` at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. You need to assign a `Parent` on which the activity indicator will draw itself. The `Owner` is the component responsible for freeing the control when the Owner is destroyed; the `Parent` is the control on which the control will be drawn (parented) for display.

The solution is to assign that parent in code:

```
Indicator := TActivityIndicator.Create(Self);
Indicator.Parent := Self; // <-- here
// Set any other properties here
```

The same issue is common on all visual controls (such as `TEdit`, `TLabel`, `TMemo`, and so forth), which all need to have a `Parent` assigned in order to have a place to paint themselves.  And in some cases, a `Parent` is required in order for various properties in the child control to function correctly when they depend on the child having an `HWND` window, which requires a `Parent` window, and so on.

If I understand your intent, I think you're going to be disappointed, however. `TActivityIndicator` is pretty static; it's not threaded, which means it will cease updating if your form is busy and doesn't process timer messages (which it uses internally).

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that, the data is loaded in another thread and then when it's finished loading I ask the UI thread to populate the fields. Also you're a legend :) that solved the problem